# Unable to get 10th variable in url string through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to get get sort_by in my php code but its seems to be that this is returning value of variable 1 with digit 0.

```
RewriteRule ^abc/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?counrty=abc&state=$1&gender=$2&r_city=$3&r_mstatus=$4&r_religion=$5&r_ethnicity=$6&r_cast=$7&r_profession=$8&r_education=$9&sort_by=$10 [NC]
```

Comment: Are you getting other 9 parameters correctly?

Comment: Yeah I am getting all other parameter correctly except the 10th one which is sort_by.

Answer (score 3):

According to Apache documentation, for `$N`, the value of `N` can only be 0-9.  So trying to get `$10` is not going to work.  You will likely need to go through two rewrite steps. So, perhaps you use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ search.php?country=$1&state=$2&gender=$3&r_city=$4&r_mstatus=$5&r_religion=$6&r_ethnicity=$7&r_cast=$8&r_profession=$8&profession_and_education_and_sort=$9 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^search\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(country=.*&state=.*&gender=.*&r_city=.*&r_mstatus=.*&r_religion=.*&r_ethnicity=.*&r_cast=.*)&profession_and_education_and_sort=([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteCond ^search\.php$ search.php?%1&r_profession=%2&r_education=%3&sort_by=%4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: By replacing abc with the country name I am getting 500 Internal Server Error error.

Comment: can you suggest me something else. or i am doing any mistake?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that 'abc', was itself something for replacement. I have update my answer.

Comment: I got the solution for my current issue. Though it is not the perfect one but this suits me in my current situation. Here I use explode($_GET) to get my last value as this value was coming in string.